# Exporting/Importing all HBase table definitions

Tags: hbase

I want to mirror our production/test HBase environments for local development and basic integration testing. While I understand that HBase is schemaless, the tables must exist and the column families need to be defined and enabled before they can be interacted with.

Is there an easy tool/script that can point to an HBase instance and generate an importable file or runnable script of all tables in that instance. Ideally this would be able to pull some small sample of data with it.

Disclaimer I am new to HBase so if I have some fundamental architectural concept wrong, feel free to correct me.

Answer (score 0):

HBase Snapshots seems to be a good choice. All you need to do is create a snapshot of the table of interest, export the snapshot to the other cluster and then execute the **clone** operation. You might these post helpful during the process :

**1. [Configuring HBase Snapshots](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/4.2.0/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_20_12.html)**

**2. [Exporting a Snapshot to Another Cluster](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/4.2.0/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_20_12.html#topic_20_12_3_unique_1)**

This will also save you from degraded region server performance and having the need to disable the table.

Is this what you need??